# how Scanner class works with user defined class as input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

recently, i read in a book about passing a user defined class as an input to scanner but it didn't explained much about the logic behind it. here's the program

```
import java.nio.CharBuffer;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

class ScannerInputBase implements Readable
{
    private int count;
    Random rand = new Random();
    ScannerInputBase(int count) { this.count = count; }
    public int read(CharBuffer cb)      //read is a method in Readable interface
    {
        if(count-- == 0)
        return -1;

        for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
        { cb.append('a'); }
        return 1;
    }
}

public class ScannerInput {

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new ScannerInputBase(5));

        while(input.hasNext()) 
        {
            print(input.next()+"-");
        }
    }
}
```

and it's output is

```
aaaaaaaaaa-
```

i have 2 questions here

1. how read() function is getting called here?
   i mean i understand it's implicitly geting called somehow but from where it's getting called.
2. a single hyphen in the output suggests that while loop in main function is iterated only once. but why only once. i was expecting output like aa-aa-aa-aa-aa-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how read() function is getting called here? i mean i understand it's
>   implicitly geting called somehow but from where it's getting called.

Answer lies in the source code of `Scanner` class for method `next()`:

```
public String next() {
    ....
    while (true) {
     .....
     if (needInput)
         readInput();
     ...
    }
}
```

Which takes us to `readInput` method which is defined as follows:

```
private void readInput() {
    ......
     try {
         n = source.read(buf);
     } catch (IOException ioe) {
    .....
     }
    .....
 }
```

We see  that `readInput` method is calling the `read` method of `source` object which is instance of `Reader` class and is passed as an argument to the `Scanner` constructor during `Scanner`'s object creation.
Now, Since you have passed the object of subclass of `Reader` as an argument to the `Scanner` constructor. And also, You have overridden the `read(CharBuffer)` method witin your class, So 
the overridden version of `read` method is being called by the `Scanner.readinput` method.

> A single hyphen in the output suggests that while loop in main function is iterated only once. but why only once. I was expecting output like aa-aa-aa-aa-aa-

Because , there is no whitespace in the string `aaaaaaaaaa` which is the default delimiter Pattern. Consequenty, all string is read in single iteration. So, `hasNext` is returning false after first iteration and the while loop terminates.

> ***Note: Always use `@Override` annotation while overriding a method
>   within subclass.***

Answer (score 0):

Scanner class is a wrapper class around streams to read and write data. It has a few [overloaded constructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.lang.Readable%29). In your case:

```
public Scanner(Readable source) {
        this(source, WHITESPACE_PATTERN);
    }
```

is invoked. Because `interface Readable` has only one method `read(CharBuffer cb)`, `ScannerInputBase` is an instaceof Readable, so the Scanner object just invokes the read() method of whatever Readable is passed.

On the second point, look at the documentation of `next()`

> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A
>   complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the
>   delimiter pattern. This method may block while waiting for input to
>   scan, even if a previous invocation of hasNext() returned true.

The default pattern used is :

```
Pattern WHITESPACE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(
                                                "\\p{javaWhitespace}+");
```

SO, it your scanner's next() call, reads everything in just one go by making multiple `read()`calls.